# How do I bind a List to datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I bind a List to datagridview? The list is `List<DataContents>`.
The purpose of the `DataContents` class is to send the data in the datagridview to this class(which has the serializable attribute). Then, I attach a value to each variable in the class(who correspond with the columns), and finally create that List , and serialize it. But now, to deserialize it, I want to bind it to the grid. How can I bind the `List<DataContents>` to the datagrid view?

**Edit**: I also have another question: The system throws an exception when I try to change the grid contents because it is databound. How can I stop this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include *attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `DataGridView.DataSource` property as your list of  `List<DataContents>`

Comment: i just edited the post, so I have another question.

Comment: @user3144238 please  update the question with related code